# How to integrate ads in App Studio

Tags: win-universal-app

Currently, I had used the App Studio for Web App Template for Windows 10,
May I ask about how to integrate the Windows Ads after extract all the source code and run in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 0):

A Hosted Web App is just a website running within the app, the Advertising can be included in the website code.